How many elements, in a set of binary strings, has exactly $k$ blocks of repeating character.
I've been thinking about this problem but I cannot find an analytical formula to get the solutions and generalize it to strings of any length.
Let $A$ be a set defined as $\left\{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6\mid a_i\in\{u,d\}\text{ for }i=1,2,...,6\right\}$, for example, $ududud\in A$ or $dduudd\in A$.
A block of u's is a repeating $u$ sub-string in an element of $A$. For example, $ududud$ has 3 blocks of u's, each one of them being of length 1. And $dduudd$ has 1 block of u's of length 2.
I want to find how many elements in $A$ are such that they have exactly $k$ blocks of $u's$ of any length. For example, there are just 1 element in $A$ with 0 blocks of $u's$, say $dddddd$. And there are just 2 elements in $A$ with 3 blocks of $u's$, say $ududud$ and $dududu$.

Note:  the problem is somewhat ambiguous.  I took "of any length" to mean that the various blocks of $u's$ need not have the same length.  But that gives a very different answer for length $6$ and $3$ blocks, as, for instance, $ududuu$ would also be a good string.  Constant length is easier, since we can just fix the length, do the routine stars and bars problem, and then sum over the possible lengths.  My posted solution addresses the variable length version.

Note:  the problem statement is ambiguous.  I took "of any length" to mean that the blocks of $u's$ might not have the same length, and that's what the following solution computes. But that does not match the example given for length $6$ and $3$ blocks.  Of course, if the lengths are all the same, that's an easier stars and bars problem, since (fixing a block length) we know exactly how much the gaps must sum to.  In any case, I'll solve the variable length problem below.
Variable Length Problem:
This is a Stars and Bars problem in disguise.
In general, say we want to consider strings of length $n$ containing exactly $m$ blocks of $u's$, call the number of such $F(n,m)$.
We write such a string as $$d^{a_0}u^{b_1}d^{b_1}\cdots u^{b_m}d^{a_m}$$
Of course $$\sum a_i+\sum b_j=n$$
Now, $a_0, a_m$ can be $0$, but all the others must be at least $1$.  Thus we define $$A_i =
\begin{cases}
a_0,  & \text{if $i=0$ } \\
a_i-1, & \text{if $0<i<m$}\\
a_m,   & \text{if $i=m$}
\end{cases}$$
$$B_i=b_i-1$$
We then see that we have $2m+1$ variables $A_i, B_i$ which are all non-negative integers and they sum to $n-2m+1$.
It follows that $F(n,m)$,  the number of ways to populate the $A_i, B_i$, is $$\boxed{\binom {n+1}{2m}}$$
Sanity Checks:  If $m=0$, we get $1$, as we should.  $F(3,1)=\binom 42=6$ and the good strings are $udd, dud, ddu, uud,duu, uuu$.  We also note that the formula implies that $F(n,m)=0$ if $2m>n+1$ and it is easily seen that this is as it should be.

I reviewed your answer, sorry for being ambiguous while writing the problem statement. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!
